# How do I translate my Bigquery query to AWS Athena query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-analytics, google-bigquery, amazon-athena

I am currently facing an issue translating this Bigquery code :

```
WITH
  dates AS (
  SELECT
    REPLACE('2020-09-10','-','') AS req_date)
SELECT
  hits.type,
  hits.hitNumber
FROM
  my_data_table_from_GA,
  UNNEST(hits) hits
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX = (
  SELECT
    req_date
  FROM
    dates)
  AND ClientId = '1234.5678910'
  AND visitstarttime = 1600000000;
```

[My output looks like this in Bigquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80SB6.png)

Similarly, I was trying to translate the query to Athena as shown below:

```
SELECT 
  hits[1].type,
  hits[1].hitNumber
  
FROM 
  my_data_table_from_GA,
  UNNEST(hits) hits
WHERE 
 (from_iso8601_date(CAST((substring(date,1,4) || '-' || substring(date,5,2) || '-' || substring(date,7,2)) AS varchar))) = date('2020-09-10') 
 AND ClientId = '1234.5678910' AND visitstarttime = 1600000000;
```

However, the output looks different [as shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGotE.png) The hitnumber is 1 throughout which shouldn't be the case and the proportion of PAGE to EVENT looks different from the output of Bigquery above.

My source data is from Google Analytics and my biggest issue is that I am not sure how to query 'hits' in Athena such that it will produce the same output at Bigquery. I tried hits.type and it threw me error saying "Expression hits is not of type ROW". That is why I put 'hits[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80SB6.png).type' but I think there is an issue with that. Would greatly appreciate if someone could assist me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem.

This worked for me:

```
SELECT 
  hit.type,
  hit.hitNumber
  
FROM 
  my_data_table_from_GA,
  UNNEST(hits) WITH ORDINALITY t(hit, index)
WHERE 
 (from_iso8601_date(CAST((substring(date,1,4) || '-' || substring(date,5,2) || '-' || substring(date,7,2)) AS varchar))) = date('2020-09-10') 
 AND ClientId = '1234.5678910' AND visitstarttime = 1600000000;
```